# Fetching data from oracle DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

I use the below code to connect to my oracle DB and execute a query. The query I used in the example simply fetches a set of rows from a table. However, I keep getting an error message that "The table or view does not exist". But, I am pretty sure that the table exists in the DB. Where am I going wrong?

```
 public void UpdateDatabase()
        {
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.144)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)));UID=mwm;PWD=mwm";
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * from Task"; 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
        }
```

The error is triggered when command.ExecuteNonQuery() is reached.

Comment: Is your connection string correct ? and are you connecting to the right database ?

Comment: @Habib.OSU  ya ya the connection string is correct. otherwise, i would have got an error in the connection string itself my friend...and ya, am connecting to the right database

Comment: What about permissions? Does the user *mwm* have permissions to use the table? Or maybe `Task` is the reserved word in Oracle (not sure about that).

Comment: Have you using a query tool like SQL Navigator, PL/SQL Developer or similar, to connect to the database (as the test user) and run your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Actually you are executing a query here therefore you should use either [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public void UpdateDatabase()
{
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = new    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.144)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)));UID=mwm;PWD=mwm";
     conn.Open();
     OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();            
     SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from \"Task\"", command))            
     DataTable t = new DataTable();
     a.Fill(t);
     command.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't work.  `SqlDataAdapter` is not compatible with Oracle.  It only works with SQLSERVER.

Answer (score 1):

Task is oracle [Reserve Word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14354/appb.htm), that is why you are getting this error. Use double quotes.

```
command.CommandText = "Select * from \"Task\"";
```

ExectueNonQuery, may not give you any error, but it will not give you the desired result. You need to do [command.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h.aspx). See the link.

You may also see this [Getting Started with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (C# Version)](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm)

Comment: are you sure??? i have passed the query as a string..wont it take it as a string ??? or will it take it as a reserve word only ???

Comment: As per Asif's answer ,one more thing I noticed, why are you using ExecuteNonQuery, it is used for insert, update or delete statements not for select

Comment: @user1501034, it will take it as a string, that is why you need to send `Select * from "Task"`

Comment: @Habib if I use ExecuteQuery, am getting an error "'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @user1501034, my bad, got confused with SQL Server, its ExecuteReader, check the updated answer and the link